# Cancel the previous ajax call and start over from beginning while change in text happens

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a ajax call on the keyup event.

The task is to show a list containing the searched school names.

At the first time, when a name is searched the list of school containing appears.

It is working perfectly fine until backspace is hit and typing again.

```
$("#InstName").keyup(function () {  
            filter = $("#InstName").val();
            textCount = $("#InstName").val().length;

            if (filter.length >= 1) {
                $("#loading").show();
                $("#InstSuggRes").hide();
                var currentRequest = null;
                currentRequest=$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "libAjaxFunctions.asp?cmd=GetInstSuggestion&instFilter=" + filter,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {

                        if (currentRequest != null) {
                            currentRequest.abort();
                        }
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        ajaxCount = ajaxCount + 1;
                        var instSugg = "";
                        $.each(data.Institutions, function (index, element) {
                            if (instSugg == "") {
                                instSugg = element;
                            }
                            else {
                                instSugg = instSugg + "<br>" + element;
                            }
                        });

                        debugger;
                        if (textCount == ajaxCount) {
                            $("#loading").hide();
                            $("#InstSuggRes").show();
                            $("#InstSuggRes").html(instSugg);
                        }
                    },

                    error: function (response) {

                        $("#loading").hide();
                        $("#InstSuggRes").show();
                        $("#InstSuggRes").html("No matching Institution");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#loading").hide();
                $("#InstSuggRes").html("");
            }

        });
```

This is what i have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the spinner to load then put setTimeout() and add the time you need in milliseconds. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cancelling AJAX requests (which only stops the client from waiting for the response, the server still receives and processes it) you should 'debounce' the event.

Debouncing means that you add a very slight delay so that if the delay is repeated before that delay expires then no AJAX request is sent. As such it increases server performance through less demand. Try this:

```js
let keydelay;
let $instSuggRes = $("#InstSuggRes");
let $loading = $('#loading');
let $instName = $("#InstName").keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(keydelay);

  keydelay = setTimeout(function() {
    filter = $instName.val();
    textCount = filter.length;

    if (filter.length >= 1) {
      $loading.show();
      $instSuggRes.hide();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "libAjaxFunctions.asp?cmd=GetInstSuggestion&instFilter=" + filter,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          var instSugg = data.Institutions.join('<br />');
          $instSuggRes.html(instSugg).show();
        },
        error: function(response) {
          $instSuggRes.html("No matching Institution").show();
        },
        complete: function() {
          $loading.hide();
        }
      });
    } else {
      $loading.hide();
      $instSuggRes.empty();
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

Note that I made a couple of tweaks to improve the logic slightly, such as caching the jQuery objects you create from selectors to reduce the number of DOM accesses, chaining some methods, and using `join()` to build the string instead of a `$.each()` loop.

Comment: What i actually need is to show a spinner.gif while the querying of the list is happening. but after the result is shown and while hit backspace the spinner is still loading. the data from the server has already came. what can i do to achieve that? any suggestions?

Comment: That's because for some reason you update the UI when `if (textCount == ajaxCount)` hits. I removed that as it made little sense

Comment: `if (textCount == ajaxCount)`  is for showing the spinner untill quering i know the issue is in that part. but i cant figure, how to change the ajaxCount while change in the searching names